# Cloud masking in MCD19A2.006 data

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, cloud-cover

I need to create a time series of aerosol optical depth using MCD19A2.006 data. I used the 'AOD_QA' band for masking the cloud. However, the following code is not working.

```
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point(85.14,27.7172).buffer(10000);
function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined) toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(0).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(0).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(0)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
var image = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES").first()
        
var qa = image.select('AOD_QA')
var Cloud_mask = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0, 2) 
var mask =  Cloud_mask.eq(1) // Clear
var maskedImage = image.updateMask(mask) 

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
.filterDate(ee.Date('2019-01-01'), ee.Date('2021-7-31'));

var collection1 = collection.filterBounds(geom)
    .select('Optical_Depth_055y')
    .map(maskedImage)
       .map(function(img) {
           return img.multiply(0.001)
          .set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of strange things in your code, explaining why it doesn't run at all:

- There's no band called `Optical_Depth_055y`
- You're calling `map(maskedImage)`. `map()` takes a function as argument, while `maskedImage` is an `ee.Image`.

To do the cloud masking, you will need to determine the mask for the individual images inside your collection. So the QA band will need to be used within the mapped function.

I suppose you want to do something like this:

```
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point(85.14, 27.7172).buffer(10000)

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2019-01-01'), ee.Date('2021-7-31'))
  .filterBounds(geom)
  .map(function(image) {
    var qa = image.select('AOD_QA')
    var Cloud_mask = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0, 2)
    var mask = Cloud_mask.eq(1) // Clear
    return image
      .select('Optical_Depth_055')
      .multiply(0.001)
      .updateMask(mask)
      .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'))
  })

function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c20df7073b6c4e2e15f0a841a128eabb